# Insert data into multiple tables from one controller/view [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forum

I have more curious questions for all you amazing people!

I am creating a forum and when you create a topic, you are also creating the first post at the same time.

I need to assign variables to certain fields.

Example: :user_id => current_user.id,

I don't have the param settings correct, so many of the fields are NULL when stored in the database.

**Models**

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy  
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :topic  
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Topics Controller**

```
# GET /topics/new
def new
  @topic = Topic.new
  @topic.posts.build
end

def create  
  @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)

  if @topic.save 
    #@topic.responses = Post.new(params[:responses])
    flash[:success] = "Topic Posted"
    redirect_to "/forums/#{@topic.forum_id}" 
  else  
    render :new  
  end   
end

def topic_params
  # last_post_at = (:last_post_at => Time.now)
  params.require(:topic).permit(
    :name, 
    :description, 
    [:last_poster_id => current_user.id], 
    [:last_post_at => Time.now], 
    [:user_id => current_user.id],
    :forum_id,
    posts_attributes: [:id, :content, :topic_id, :user_id => current.user.id] )
end
```

**Post Controller**

```
# GET /posts/new
def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create  
  @post = Post.new(
    :content => params[:post][:content], 
    :topic_id => params[:post][:topic_id], 
    :user_id => current_user.id)  

  if @post.save  
    @topic = Topic.find(@post.topic_id)  
    @topic.update_attributes(
      :last_poster_id => current_user.id, 
      :last_post_at => Time.now)  
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post."  
    redirect_to "/topics/#{@post.topic_id}"  
  else  
    render :action => 'new'  
  end  
end
```

**_form for View/Topic**

```
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %>
  <% if params[:forum] %>
    <input type="hidden" 
    id="topic_forum_id" 
    name="topic[forum_id]" 
    value="<%= params[:forum] %>" />
  <% end %>  

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :posts do |p| %>

    <%= p.label :content %><br />
    <%= p.text_area :content %>

  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass  ONLY when    :content => params[:post][:content] is in the create post located in the topic controller. If I remove that, the topic is created, but there is no new field in the post table. Actually, now when I create a topic, the content field isn't showing up in the form as well, just allows people to create a name and description field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely be looking for a function called:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for
```

You put this into the model you're working with (in your case Post) and it will pass paeans for the nested model through to the corresponding controller

There is a good [RailsCast about this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and I've gr some experience with it too. If you want me to post working live code, let me know (I'm on my iPhone)

---

**Live Code**

Models

```
#app/models/image_post.rb
belongs_to :post, :class_name => 'Post'
belongs_to :image, :class_name => 'Image'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :image, :allow_destroy => true

#app/models/post.rb
has_many :images, -> { uniq }, :class_name => 'Image', :through => :images_posts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :images_posts, :class_name => 'ImagePost'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images_posts, :allow_destroy => true
```

Controller

```
    def new
            @post = Post.new
            @post.images_posts.build.build_image
    end

    def create
            #Using Inherited Resources Gem
            create! 
    end

    private
    def permitted_params
            {:post => params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, images_posts_attributes: [:caption, image_attributes: [:image]] )}
    end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for [:admin, resource], :html => { :multipart => true }  do |f| %>
        <table class="resource_table">
                <thead>
                        <th colspan="2"><%= params[:action].capitalize %> <%= resource_class %></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="form">
                        <% attributes.each do |attr| %>
                                <tr class="<%= cycle('odd', '')%>">
                                        <td><%= resource_class.human_attribute_name(attr) %></td>
                                        <td>
                                                <% if attr == "body" %>
                                                        <%= f.text_area attr, :rows => 60, :cols => 80, :class => "redactor" %>
                                                <% else %>
                                                        <%= f.text_field attr, :value => resource.public_send(attr).to_s %>
                                                <% end %>
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                        <% end %>
                        <%= f.fields_for :images_posts do |images_posts| %>
                                <%= images_posts.fields_for :image do |images| %>
                                        <tr>
                                                <td>Image</td>
                                                <td><%= images.file_field :image %></td>
                                        </tr>
                                <% end %>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Caption</td>
                                        <td><%= images_posts.text_field :caption %></td>
                                </tr>
                        <% end %>
                        <tr class="dull">
                                <td colspan="2"><%= f.submit "Go" %></td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts in Post (just forgot to add it to the code here). So can you post a working live code in case I'm missing something.

Comment: Btw we used a has_many :through relationship, so we have the extra model to deal with; but if you can't decipher it, please let me know

Comment: Okay I am slightly confused. Does Create! use the private params? and if not, where is the private params used? I feel like my code is very similar to this. I think I understand what I need to do now, but now I need to create a new question to solve a new problem. Haha. Thank you.

Comment: Hey create! is from [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) sorry. What's your new problem? I'll help you fix it!

Comment: Using your suggestions (without the gem), I managed to get it so when you create the topic, it creates the post. However, some of the topic and post fields in the table are NULL, because I need to assign it special variables (Like :last_poster_id => current_user.id). I edited my original post to show my code. How do you use strong params that have fields that need certain variables?

Comment: It seems that your strong params are okay? Can you post specifically which fields are appearing as Null?

Comment: last_poster_id, last_post_at and both user_id for the topic and post tables

Answer (score 0):

Use accepts_nested_attributes

```
class topic
 accepts_nested_attributes :posts
end

class post
  accepts_nested_attributes :topic
end
```

Then in form you can use fields_for posts while creating topic form 
Also in post form fileds_for for topic

Comment: I think I already have all this and its still not saving when i create a new topic.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to [fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) the post params as

```
params[:topic].fetch(:post_attributes, nil)
```

Rails 4 has been sanitized the mass-assignment to be called as [strong_params](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/)
[Example](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Comment: I used Strong_params at first and it did create posts for me... However, I was unable to change the variable data before it was entered. like... :Last_poster_id => current_user.id wouldn't work, so last_poster_id would be null.

    def topic_params
      params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :description, [:last_poster_id => current_user.id], 
        [:last_post_at => Time.now], :forum_id,
        posts_attributes: [:id, :content, :topic_id, :user_id] )
    end