# Perform a Insert action into a table while login in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save information about users' login history.

So I want to make a Insert action when a user signs in.

That means by clicking `"sign in`" button my system authenticates the user and also saves some information into the database.

After reading this [question-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459732/insert-data-into-multiple-tables-from-one-controller-view-rails-4) it goes over my head. Because I am new in Rails.

How can I do that? Give me some ideas in simple way(if exist).

Comment: Hi - here at Stack Overflow we expect you to do some research on the topic, then have a go at it yourself, then come to us when you hit a snag (eg a bug/error that you are getting). Then, we expect you to give us more information about your system - we can't help you based on a verbal description, so show us the relevant code that you have tried so far (even if it's broken or incomplete or just has comment saying "this is where I want to save the login time"). Then we can *begin* to help you :)

Comment: Hi, I am new in Rails. So after doing some search in google I can not understand what is the solution. FYI I am using devise for authentication.

Comment: Sure so... update your question to show us what research you did and what you didn't understand about it. (don't put it in the comments as it should be part of your original question).

Answer (score 1):

you can make insert action in this method and keep it in application controller. I hope it helps.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
#insert actions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge if you have gem 'devise' installed it should do the trick.
It depends do you want to show the history to users or just want to keep it for yourself.
If just for your own convenience .. then you might wanna install 'devise' gem to your gem file and follow the instruction in git hub.

if already installed 'devise' gem run following command in terminal it will open the rails console  (shutdown ctrl+D/command+D)

```
$ rails c
```

## Assuming that your **Devise** model name is '**User**' run following in console

```
$ User.all
```

Bingo it will return you list of users and their login history , ip etc.

## example

```
irb(main):002:0> 
<User id: 4, email: "user_4@bhram.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$J3LtTG1Lq.4u4jdu437q.e94IdOtlzSqCxTWLZ/yA.5...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 2, current_sign_in_at: "2015-05-19 05:29:52", last_sign_in_at: "2015-05-18 18:45:54", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2015-05-18 18:45:54", updated_at: "2015-05-19 05:29:52">
```

if you dig a little you can see 
sign_in_count: 2, 
current_sign_in_at: "2015-05-19 05:29:52", 
last_sign_in_at: "2015-05-18 18:45:54"
..

pherhaps you want you may create a new table to keep track of history and   better view

Or if you want to display it to the users like banking websites does

## Assuming that you have another linked Scaffold Model 'xyz' so in show view you may edit this

```
<%= @xyz.user.sign_in_count %>
```

similarly you can use other commands as well